# Automated image optimization for websites - literature and resources

Tags: image, optimization, web, automation

I have to make a presentation about image optimization for websites *for my university*. The focus should be on **automatization**.

I found some good resources about image optimization, e.g. the book "**Even faster websites**" by Steve Souders. Although he mentioned some good tools to optimize images (e.g. [Smush-it](http://www.smushit.com/ysmush.it/)), he doesn't provide any real solution to automate this task.

**My question is:** Are there tools/patterns to automate image optimization during development? During deployment? Smush-it is cool, by I still have to upload each and every images by hand. Is there any tooling for popular IDEs? Or web-development framework (Play!, Flask,...)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Give the image some bash love.

"find folder/path -type f -name '*.PNG' -exec sips -s formatOptions  40 {} \;"

This code with optimize ever picture and in every subfolder you have.